# TinyMCE editor fixed size with no scrollers?

Tags: editor, tinymce

At the moment I have this:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
// General options
mode : "exact",
elements : "fkField, lkField, ukcField, khField",
theme : "advanced",
plugins : "table",
width : "300",
height: "185",
// Theme options
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "fontsizeselect, bold,italic,underline,bullist, cleanup, |,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "tablecontrols", 
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "", 
theme_advanced_buttons4 : "", 

theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "bottom",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "center",
theme_advanced_resizing : false
    });
```

This gives me a editor with the size of 300x185.

Now in this editor, I would like to do so you can only write until the editor is full. (without the scroller)

So you are unable to enter more text, and the scroller should not appear (disable scrolling)

Right now you can at the bottom of inside the editor just make new line and it will add the scroller <- which i do not want to happen

How can i do this? Is this unpossible? I have made research for some time now, but maybe it's just me searching wrong..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write an own plugin. Check the editor height on each Keystroke (you may use the built in tinymce event `onKeyUp`). If the heigth changes remove the last inserted code.

**EDIT:** Howto get the current editor iframe heigth

```
    var currentfr=document.getElementById(editor.id + '_ifr');
    if (currentfr.contentDocument && currentfr.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight) { //ns6 syntax
        currentfr.height = currentfr.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight + 26;
    }
    else if (currentfr.Document && currentfr.Document.body.scrollHeight) { //ie5+ syntax
            currentfr.height = currentfr.Document.body.scrollHeight;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can i get the current height of the editor? And how can i remove the last inserted code?
See http://jsfiddle.net/J7cKD/

Comment: have a look here on howto setup fiddle with tinymce: http://jsfiddle.net/R2rHn/5/

Comment: I know i have not setup the tinymce correctly in jsfiddle, i just used it to paste the code on how far i have come. Can you tell me how i can get the current heigh of the editor and how you can remove the last inserted code?

Comment: that worked, excellent! Last thing, how can i remove the last inserted code?

Answer (score 1):

add in a ccs file the following code

```
.mceContentBody{
         overflow-y:hidden!important;
      }
```

and add the path of css file in content_css attribut of tinymce

```
content_css : /path/to/css/file.ss
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding this to my extra tinyMCE CSS file:

```
IFRAME {overflow:hidden;}
```

Previously, the scrollbars were only off in Firefox. This fixes it for Chrome as well. However, it does add a gray bar the side of a scrollbar at the bottom, so I need to enlarge the height of my text editor.

Comment: This doesn't fix the actual problem. The problem was that the user shouldn't be allowed to type more than the provided space.

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked by just adding rules to a regular stylesheet, it wasn't needed to add a css file to `content_css` attribute (example is in scss)

```
.my-tinymce-container {
  width: 200px;
  .mce-edit-area {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot simpler and easy solution would be:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#container',
    },
    init_instance_callback: function (ed) {
        tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().style.overflow = 'hidden'
    },
});
```

Explanation:
In Init **callback** get the body for TinyMCE and change style as required.

In this case to remove scrollbar  `overflow = 'hidden'`.

Comment: I like the idea of this solution, but it still allows the user to keep typing in the box and it will cut off the first line of text. Any way around this?