# A WYSIWYG Where it's possible to limit the text/height

Tags: editor, wysiwyg

Ok, so I tried out tinyMCE.

After no luck and a lot of research on how to limit the editors content, I'm looking for other alternatives.

These are the needs for the WYSIWYG:

- Able to have these function/buttons: bold,italic,underline,bull list, table controls
- Able to limit the input. If I set the editor to 300 width x 500 height, and you type more than the height, it should NOT apply a scroller and you should be unable to write more.
- Able to set multiple editors in one page

Which WYSIWYG editor can fill my needs?

Comment: It's possible that the answer is "none" - this is not trivial. The WYSIWYG editor would have to check *with every keypress event* whether the planned change to the content would exceed the defined height, and block it if it does. It's well possible such a solution doesn't exist, and would need to be built (with a *lot* of effort)

Comment: @Pekka i tried to built what you mention here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609104/tinymce-remove-last-inserted-code , but it didnt work well. Hmm.. what can i do? I would like to have WYSIWYG on my site, and the output box where the content of the editor appears has fixed height+width, so i need to do the same with the editor so you cant enter more than the height can 'hold'.. Help :(

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to use a div element and put the content of the editor inside that div. The div should have set a width (using css).

```
<div class="calculation_preview"></div>
```

And the css should be something like:

```
div.calculation_preview {
   width: 200px;
   visibility: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left:0px;
}
```

After each key-stroke, you can measure the height of the div (using the function offsetHeight on the div).
If it is too height, remove the last character the user entered.

To restore the previous content, you can declare a javascript variable as for example:

```
var savedContent = "";
```

If you have some initial content in your editor, then you should initialize the variable with that content.
For each key-stroke, you do the following:

```
// Get current editor content:
var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});
// Measure the new height of the content:
var measurer = document.getElementById("calculation_preview");
measurer.innerHTML = content;
if(measurer.offsetHeight > 100) {
   // Content is too big.. restore previous:
   tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(savedContent, {format : 'raw'});
} else {
   // Content height is ok .. save to variable:
   savedContent = content;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607659/tinymce-editor-fixed-size-with-no-scrollers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609104/tinymce-remove-last-inserted-code

Comment: In tinyMCE. So show me how i can remove the last character the user entered ,this way? And the code u pasted why does it have visibility:hidden

Comment: visibility set to hidden, because you only use it to measure the height of the resulting div ;) It's just an idea, but you you could use the undo function of tinyMCE. Another possibility would be to copy the content before adding the character (using the innerHTML function), and restore it later if necessary..

Comment: you are more than welcome to answer my other questions, or edit this answer on how exactly i can copy the content before adding char/ running undo in the background.

Comment: It might be better, to use the above restore code in the onChange callback: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onChange

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE or ck editor should meet your needs.

Regarding the scroll issue, try using jquery and the keypress event along to test the length of the content in the div holding the editor. You could also combine this with a character counter on the screen to dynamically display how many characters a user has left.

```
charCount = $(this).val().length;
```