# Trying to make WYSIWYG on my page

Tags: wysiwyg

Being unlucky with this:
[A WYSIWYG Where it's possible to limit the text/height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616319/a-wysiwyg-where-its-possible-to-limit-the-text-height)

What should I do, i would like to have WYSIWYG, but the WYG part, (what you get) is inside a fixed sized box.

And the editors out there makes scrollers/expands in height when you write more than the height you set the editor to.

So what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden` in the right place should do the job.

For CKEDitor, see  [CKEditor: Class or ID for editor body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844569/ckeditor-class-or-id-for-editor-body)